# php using live server as oppose to local server despite virtual host settings

Tags: ubuntu, php, virtualhost

I had planned on migrating a website to another server,

So having copied the code and database etc, and changed my hosts file on windows, everything worked almost as expected. I could load the site and use it away for testing prior to repointing the domain,

However there is one piece of functionality that uses a php library that finds image urls in html code. Because of this I must use external http urls to access the images, even though the images are on the same server.

My issue,

Even though everything else about the site is using the new local server, this piece of code is still looking at the live server as if no virtual host settings were set up for it.

In my /etc/sites-enabled/example.conf I have a virtual host set up...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/html/example/cgi-bin/
<Location /cgi-bin>
Options +ExecCGI
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/www/html/example/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/example/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working as expected bar the one issue as described above, it seems to be ignoring it in that case.

I would be confident this would work if I changed the actual A records for that domain, but I need to test it first.

EDIT: Just to clarify more,

I am using Apache2 with Ubuntu.

My core question is,

When my php code is working with an image url, e.g. `<img src="http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg" />`, why only in one particular case is it loading this image from the REAL server that that domain is pointing to, and not the local server like everything else?

Comment: Can you clarify this please? For example - what web server are you using? (presumably apache based upon that syntax but it could be a variant) Also, you haven't actually asked a question yet!

Comment: apologies, some more info added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the PHP code is executing on the new server, not on your client.  Unless you make some change to the DNS configuration of that server (e.g. adding an entry to the hosts file), PHp will still believe (correctly) that www.example.com is on the live server.  PHP doesn't look into the apache configuration and has no knowledge that the server it's running on has an apache that will respond to www.example.com requests.